# Angular 8 how to convert $("#chat_panel").animate({ width: "toggle" }) to typescript?

Tags: angular, toggle, angular-animations

I need to convert this jquery to angular8

```
$("#chat_panel").animate({ width: "toggle" });
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary difference between Angular and jQuery is accessing the DOM element. When jQuery uses the `$` notation, Angular uses `ViewChild`. The animation code should be identical.

```js
import { ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class YourComponent {

  @ViewChild('#chat_panel') chatPanel: ElementRef;

  animateChatPanel(): void {
     this.chatPanel.nativeElement.animate({
       ... // your animation code here
     }); 
  }
}
```